# Error when trying to import mp3 files using JavaFX

Tags: java, macos, javafx

So i tried running my application and it gave me this warning in terminal:

```
Jan 12, 2015 8:57:00 PM com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PrismImageLoader2$PrismLoadListener imageLoadWarning
WARNING: null
Jan 12, 2015 8:57:00 PM com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PrismImageLoader2$PrismLoadListener imageLoadWarning
WARNING: Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment`
```

It will go through two songs (out of six) in `/Dir` and then stop unexpectedly.

How do I get it to not throw this warning? And how do I get it to go through the entire directory?

```
public void getMusicDirectory() {
    try {
        File folder = new File("./Dir");
        File[] contents = folder.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
            String name = contents[i].getName();
            //System.out.println(name);

            if (name.indexOf(".mp3") == -1) {
                continue;
            }

            //System.out.println(name + "continuing");
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(contents[i]);
            int size = (int)contents[i].length();
            //System.out.println(size);
            file.skip(size - 128);
            byte[] last128 = new byte[128];
            file.read(last128);
            String id3 = new String(last128);
            String tag = id3.substring(0, 3);
            if (tag.equals("TAG")) {
                songsDir.add(new Song((new MediaPlayer(new Media(contents[i].toURI().toString()))),id3));
                file.close();
            } else
                file.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error -- " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

That is the code that I am using. I do not understand why it will not go through all of the files, or why it is triggering the warnings.

Comment: Some questions: 1. Does it always fail on the same file? (Try loading just the single file it fails on, for example.) 2. Is there any more detail on the error (e.g. a stack trace, etc)? 3. Is your `Song` class loading an image somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I had an almost similar problem and it seems the problem was with the data type I was using. I was using **blob** in my maria db database but once I changed it to **LONGBLOB**, it worked perfectly. I was trying to load the image from the database to a javafx Imageview